# how to make select2 with jquery I

Tags: jquery, yii2, jquery-select2

I'm using kartik-v/yii2-widget-select2 like follows:

```
use kartik\select2\Select2; 

echo $form->field($model, 'state_1')->widget(Select2::classname(), [ 
'data' => $data,     
'options' => [
   'placeholder' => 'Select a state ...'],     
   'pluginOptions' => ['allowClear' => true],
 ]);
```

In client side i need a plus button, by pushing it users can make new select2 input
I used jquery `clone(true, true)` function to generate select2 by pushing plus button.But in this situation events not working properly.

please help me with this.

Comment: If you are saying that the select2 is not being applied to the select tag when you create it usually that means that you need to re-fire the event to the newly created select tag. Usually something like `$('select-new').select2()`

Answer (score 0):

Found some good base in yii2-dynamicform (https://github.com/wbraganca/yii2-dynamicform) for cloning form elements. However the select2 part is outdated and needs some fixes.

I incorporated relevant changes for personal use in this fork (anyone is welcome to use it, but minified version hasn't been updated yet):
https://github.com/probkiller/yii2-dynamicform

However, if its just the select2 element that needs cloning, you can consider using following code:

```
let $hasSelect2 = $('#yourWrapperForSelect2Clone').find('[data-krajee-select2]');
    if ($hasSelect2.length > 0) {
        $hasSelect2.each(function() {
            let id = $(this).attr('id');
            let configSelect2 = eval($(this).attr('data-krajee-select2'));
            let select2Ops = $(this).attr('data-s2-options');

            if ($(this).data('select2')) {
                $(this).select2('destroy');
            }

            // You can omit this block if you are not using depdrop
            let configDepdrop = $(this).data('depdrop');
            if (configDepdrop) {
                configDepdrop = $.extend(true, {}, configDepdrop);
                $(this).removeData().off();
                $(this).unbind();
                _restoreKrajeeDepdrop($(this));
            }

            $.when($('#' + id).select2(configSelect2)).done(initS2Loading(id, select2Ops));

           // You can omit this block if you are not using depdrop
           if (configDepdrop) {
                let loadingText = (configDepdrop.loadingText) ? configDepdrop.loadingText : 'Loading ...';
                initDepdropS2(id, loadingText);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I used this code but it throws error  "TypeError: this.dataAdapter is null" in line $(this).select2('destroy'); for cloned select2

Comment: the above code is just the part used to fix the validation js after you have cloned and fixed the clone object's id, name etc.. Check if the error is still there after these steps. You can always use yii2-dynamic-form.js from above mentioned library as your guide